# get serial com port description in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, serial-port

I want to retrieve serial com port information as device manager shows. For example, "Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)".
I know use command "mode" to retrieve serial port list, but there is no description like "Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL". How do I get this information in windows batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated answer

... was provided by the original asker in the comments below.  Apparently `Win32_SerialPort` doesn't include USB->Serial devices.  William's solution to this is to query [`Win32_PnPEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Just so I still feel useful, here's a way to scrape that list and set each line into a variable:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

:: wmic /format:list strips trailing spaces (at least for path win32_pnpentity)
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:list ^| find "COM"') do (
    call :setCOM "%%~J"
)

:: display all _COM* variables
set _COM

:: end main batch
goto :EOF

:setCOM <WMIC_output_line>
:: sets _COM#=line
setlocal
set "str=%~1"
set "num=%str:*(COM=%"
set "num=%num:)=%"
set str=%str:(COM=&rem.%
endlocal & set "_COM%num%=%str%"
goto :EOF
```

---

#### Original answer

Use `wmic` with `Win32_SerialPort`, something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('wmic path Win32_SerialPort get DeviceID^,Caption^,Description^,Name^,ProviderType /format:list ^| find "="') do (
    set "%%I"
)

echo %DeviceID%
echo %Caption%
echo %Description%
echo %Name%
echo %ProviderType%
```

See the documentation for [Win32_SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what other properties you can query.  I'll leave it as an exercise for you to find a way to set the variables uniquely so you aren't overwriting them with iterations over each COM port.  Enjoy!

Comment: This script does not list devices such as a USB -> RS232 Virtual COM port.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling So far, the closest solution to that I've found is a PowerShell snippet on the [`Win32_USBControllerDevice` documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follows: `powershell -command "gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID | Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer Description,Service,DeviceID"` (which probably needs the `%` double-pumped in a batch script).  Not sure how to translate that to `wmic`, but the PowerShell cmdlets could probably be massaged to dial in the results you want.

Comment: @rojo, I find that maybe we can use Win32_PnPEntity: `wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:table | find "COM"`

Comment: Thanks, was a bit cryptic for a linuxer, yet easy enough to modify. For Batch noobs, such as myself, that `endlocal & <some_cmd>` part can be expanded as `endlocal & ( <cmd_1>; <cmd_2> )` to multiple actions. Apparently, `endlocal` flushes local scope, however, that `& ...` part still has access to the scope and can smuggle variables out of the function/procedure. If one can cope with script-level variable side effects, it is not a necessity (put all script in a `setlocal ... endlocal` block to not leak to terminal). Still, just use the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `mode` command to get details of available COM ports..

Comment: Wow! it is a good command ... it gives everything except a port description.