# OpenCV with multiple webcams - how to tell which camera is which in code?

Tags: opencv, camera, webcam

Previously I've used industrial cameras with Ethernet connections and distinct IP addresses for multiple camera setups.  Now I'm attempting a multiple camera setup with OpenCV and I'm not sure how to match the OpenCV `VideoCapture` ID to a certain camera.

I should probably use my current situation as an example to make my question more clear.  I currently have 3 cameras connected.  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.  Here is my output from `lsusb` (omitting everything except the 3 Logitech webcams I have connected):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C930e
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C930e
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam
```

As you can see I have 2 `C930e`s and one `OrbiCam` connected.  Based on this very helpful post:

https://superuser.com/questions/902012/how-to-identify-usb-webcam-by-serial-number-from-the-linux-command-line

I found I could get the serial number of the cams like so:

```
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 046d:0843 | grep -i serial
  iSerial                 1 D2DF1D2E
  iSerial                 1 99A8F15E
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 046d:0892 | grep -i serial
  iSerial                 1 C83E952F
```

Great, so I now have a way to uniquely identify each camera based on the serial numbers stored in the cam's memory (`D2DF1D2E`, `99A8F15E`, and `C83E952F`).

The problem is, opening a webcam connection in OpenCV is done as follows:

```
vidCapForCamX = cv2.VideoCapture(OPEN_CV_VID_CAP_ID_FOR_CAM_X)
vidCapForCamY = cv2.VideoCapture(OPEN_CV_VID_CAP_ID_FOR_CAM_Y)
vidCapForCamZ = cv2.VideoCapture(OPEN_CV_VID_CAP_ID_FOR_CAM_Z)
```

Where camera X, Y, and Z are the 3 cameras I need to use, each for a different determined purpose, and `OPEN_CV_VID_CAP_ID_FOR_CAM_X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the OpenCV `VideoCapture` IDs.  Right now, I'm relating cameras to the OpenCV VideoCapture IDs with the following manual process:

1) Make a test script like this:

```
# cam_test.py

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)


while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    keyPress = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if keyPress == ord('q'):
        break
    # end if

# end while

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

2) Try numbers 0-99 for the `VideoCapture` parameter until I find the 3 magic numbers for my 3 attached cameras.  In my current example they are 0, 2, and 4.

3) Each time I find a valid `VideoCapture` ID, wave my hand in front of each camera until I determine which one that `VideoCapture` ID is for, then write down which camera in my project that needs to correspond to, ex in my case:

```
0 => serial D2DF1D2E => cam X
2 => serial 99A8F15E => cam Y
4 => serial C83E952F => cam Z
```

4) Edit my code (or a stored config file or database field) so cam X uses `VideoCapture` ID 0, cam Y uses `VideoCapture` ID 2, etc.

I should clarify that cameras X, Y, and Z are in different positions and serve different purposes, i.e. if I use `VideoCapture` ID 4 for cam X the application wouldn't work (they have to be mapped a certain way as above).

Clearly for a production application this routine is not acceptable.

I realize I can do something like this:

```
import cv2

openCvVidCapIds = []

for i in range(100):
    try:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
        if cap is not None and cap.isOpened():
            openCvVidCapIds.append(i)
        # end if
    except:
        pass
    # end try
# end for

print(str(openCvVidCapIds))
```

To get a list of the valid OpenCV `VideoCapture` IDs, but I still have to do the manual hand wave thing to determine which OpenCV `VideoCapture` IDs corresponds to each camera.

To make matters worse, swapping which camera is connected to which physical port on a device shuffles the OpenCV `VideoCapture` IDs, so if any camera connection is changed, or a cam is added or removed the manual process has to be repeated for all cameras.

***So my question is***, is there some genius way (in code, not a manual way) to relate the serial number of each camera or some other unique ID stored in the cam's memory to the magic numbers that OpenCV seems to come up with for `VideoCapture` IDs?

***To put my question another way***, I need to write a function `camSerialNumToOpenCvVidCapId` that could be used like so:

```
vidCapForCamX = cv2.VideoCapture(camSerialNumToOpenCvVidCapId(D2DF1D2E))
vidCapForCamY = cv2.VideoCapture(camSerialNumToOpenCvVidCapId(99A8F15E))
vidCapForCamZ = cv2.VideoCapture(camSerialNumToOpenCvVidCapId(C83E952F))
```

Is this possible and how could this be done?

P.S. I'm comfortable with OpenCV C++ or Python, any helpful answers using either would be greatly appreciated.

--- Edit ---

This question:

[OpenCV VideoCapture device index / device number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298588/opencv-videocapture-device-index-device-number/41299177)

Has a response (not accepted) that pertains to using Windows API calls, but I'm using Ubuntu.

--- Edit2 ---

@ Micka, here is what I have for cameras in /dev/:

```
$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 20 12:26 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Nov 20 12:26 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Nov 20 12:26 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 3 Nov 20 12:26 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 4 Nov 20 12:26 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 5 Nov 20 12:26 /dev/video5
```

I'm not sure if this helps

--- Edit3 ---

After considering this some more what I really need is a cam property in OpenCV to identify each camera uniquely.  After getting a list of available `VideoCapture` IDs as mentioned above, if there was a property like:

```
serialNum = cv2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_SERIAL_NUM)
```

Then it would be easy, but there does not seem to be such a property or anything similar (after checking PyCharm auto-complete for `cv2.CAP_PROP_*` and reading the OpenCV docs for `VideoCapture`).

Comment: are the cameras listed here? /dev/video*

Comment: @ Micka I added the information you have mentioned to the question description, please see Edit2

Comment: afaik, you can capture device videoX with VideoCapture(X). Now, to find the mapping between usb (with serial number information etc.) and videoX you can try thr 2nd answer from https://superuser.com/questions/902012/how-to-identify-usb-webcam-by-serial-number-from-the-linux-command-line

Answer (score 5):

For the solution you found, you need root privileges. On my setup with Ubuntu20 this is not required for:

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/video0
```

This outputs properties of first camera detected. Pipe it through "grep" to filter out specific property that is different for all cameras like "ID_SERIAL=". You can then use "cut" to remove beginning of this string "ID_SERIAL=" and leave just the value like:

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/video0 | grep ID_SERIAL= | cut -d "=" -f 2
```

In Python you can run external command to get this info like:

```
def get_cam_serial(cam_id):
    # Prepare the external command to extract serial number. 
    p = subprocess.Popen('udevadm info --name=/dev/video{} | grep ID_SERIAL= | cut -d "=" -f 2'.format(cam_id),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    # Run the command
    (output, err) = p.communicate()

    # Wait for it to finish
    p.status = p.wait()

    # Decode the output
    response = output.decode('utf-8')

    # The response ends with a new line so remove it
    return response.replace('\n', '')
```

To acquire all the camera serial numbers, just loop through several camera ID's. On my setup trying camera ID 0 and 1 target the same camera. Also 2 and 4 target the second camera, so the loop can have 2 for step. Once all ID's are extracted, place them in a dictionary to be able to associate cam ID with serial number. The complete code could be:

```
serials = {}
FILTER = "ID_SERIAL="


def get_cam_serial(cam_id):
    p = subprocess.Popen('udevadm info --name=/dev/video{} | grep {} | cut -d "=" -f 2'.format(cam_id, FILTER),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    p.status = p.wait()
    response = output.decode('utf-8')
    return response.replace('\n', '')


for cam_id in range(0, 10, 2):
    serial = get_cam_serial(cam_id)
    if len(serial) > 6:
        serials[cam_id] = serial

print('Serial numbers:', serials)
```

Comment: It will be an even better answer if you are explaining code.

Comment: Any way to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

It is not very difficult to do. In Linux browse to the directory

> /dev/v4l/by-id/

This directory lists all the webcams connected to your system with names like **usb-046d_081b_31296650-video-index0** Copy this id and use it in your code in the following manner:

```
cv::VideoCapture camera;
camera.open("/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_081b_31296650-video-index0");

cv::Mat frame;
camera >> frame;
```

For different cameras you can first note down their ids and then refer them in your code.

Comment: The challenge may sometimes lie in choosing between several v4l devices that a single connected camera exposes, some of which do not provide or are not meant to provide a quality camera experience.